# Choosing a Relay to Operate Solenoid Valve

Tags: sensor, relay, solenoid

I'm working on a project in which a solenoid valve needs to be triggered when a sensor detects a passing object. I have the concept and general design down, however I need some help with the specifics.

Essentially, a photoelectric retro-reflective sensor will detect an object, send its signal to a relay which in turn will trigger a 24 Vdc solenoid valve.

- The sensor's signal voltage is listed as approximately Uv / < 3V and output current Imax is 100 mA

[Sensor Datasheet](https://www.sick.com/au/en/photoelectric-sensors/photoelectric-sensors/w12g/wl12g-3o2431/p/p241372)

- The solenoid is 24 Vdc and 8W, with an inrush VA of 25 and hold VA of 14.5

[Solenoid Datasheet](http://www.ode.co.nz/PDF%27s/21WA4KOV130.pdf)

- 24 Vdc power supply is to be used

Question 1: What data do I need to consider (from that listed above or otherwise) when choosing a relay? Specific relay suggestions are welcome :)

Question 2: Once the relay has been chosen and provided its specs suit the sensor and solenoid, is any further circuitry required i.e. a diode for the inductive load etc?

As is probably evident from my questions I'm quite inexperienced in this area so sorry for any ambiguity but thank you, your help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need a relay that switches at least 24V and 25A with a coil rated for 3V maybe 2.5V. Yes you need a 25A+ fly-back diode  across the output of the solenoid to protect the contacts, and a 1A fly-back on the coil side to protect the sensor.

Comment: VA of 25 is only 1+ Amp at 24V

Comment: Oops you are right as usual @TonyStewart.EEsince'75. Read what it says not what you think it says Trevor... (Slaps self on back of head.) I did think that was a tad huge too.

Comment: No worries mate.

Comment: There are many coils available for this valve. The 'W' figure applies to the DC coil options, and all the VA figures apply **only** to AC coils.

Comment: Maybe this sucker http://raise.rockwellautomation.com/RAConfig/resultsComponents.asp?CID=FD97DE434DE247119FB79660C98B1233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are going to specify a DC coil, the only relevant number is the '8W' figure, which implies a nominal current of 333mA @24VDC.

Just about any power relay with 5A-10A rating will work, probably with a lifetime of many hundreds of thousands, perhaps millions, of operations, but you should put a diode across the solenoid coil so that the relay contact does not arc excessively when the contacts open.

Make sure the diode is connected correctly (reverse-biased) or you will probably damage the relay and the diode. A 1N4004 will work fine for this application.

You could also use a DC-output SSR if you wanted to avoid a mechanical relay- you would typically still need the diode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2JXNH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If it's not a SS relay I'd put diodes on both sides. He does not want to risk blowing up that sensor either. It does not look cheap.

Comment: As @Trevor says, you will need a diode across the relay coil if it's a mechanical type. If you use a PCB module as Tony suggests it may have a diode and drive transistor (and even an optoisolator) on there already.

Comment: Does the signal voltage from the sensor come in to consideration at all? @SpehroPefhany

Comment: @Seano If your supply voltage is 24VDC it can drive a 24VDC coil relay directly, up to 100mA. A typical power relay as I suggest might be 1-2W for the coil, so that is plenty.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks for your help! So just to confirm, the relay would be connected to a constant power supply of 24 Vdc as well as to the output of the sensor to energise the coil? Just making sure my heads fully around this.

Comment: The sensor is a PNP type so the relay coil goes from the output to ground return on the 24V supply (with  a diode across it). The contact switches (say) the + side of the 24V and your solenoid coil goes to the ground return on the 24V supply. Again, with a diode. See schematic edit above. You could use the N.C. contact on the relay if you need to reverse the action. There are DIN rail-mount socketed relays that might suit your process control type application better than a hobbyist module.

Answer (score 1):

VA of 25 is only 1+ Amp at 24V but considering turn off arc, I would use 5A non gold plated contacts using an optoisolator driving 10mA from 3V (e.g. some require selection of series R for preferred IR current. ) with  decoupling cap on 24V supply on Relay board for EMI reduction.

These are cheap (2$) and optoisolated as well in 5,12,24V types with many current ratings.

I suggest a 5A Relay but photo shows 25A ($2 on ee bae )

[image]

Or this multichannel one for future expansion/

It is not a 3V sensor but 5V.

THe sensor is 5V PNP <100mA pullup compatible with 5V Opto drivers for 15~20mA for high side drive with built in R on Relay cards that are PNP or NPN compatible.

http://www.ebay.ca/itm/OMRON-4-Channel-5V-Relay-Module-Opto-couple-For-Arduino-UNO-Mega-R3-AVR-ARM-/301286279825?hash=item46260fca91:g:RIsAAOSwgkRVVBzK

This one is better with many sources to buy.

[image]

> Use suitable twisted pair for all drive pairs for improved EMI control.
>   OMRON makes high quality relays.

**Reverse diode clamp across output contacts are necessary to prevent high voltage impulse voltage with solenoid loads on turn off.  (1N400x or equiv.)**

Comment: By the look of his other parts I think he may need something more industrial.

Comment: Maybe this sucker...http://raise.rockwellautomation.com/RAConfig/resultsComponents.asp?CID=FD97DE434DE247119FB79660C98B1233

Comment: OR this one $143 https://www.galco.com/buy/RK-Electronics/ISR-24V-10K